# IF conditional for text value in specific cell

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I have two columns ("D" and "E") and in the cells from column "D" I can select from a drop-down list. One of these options is "NA". What I want to do is that, if you select the value "NA" from the drop-down list (for example, in "D5"), the cell that is in the same row, in column "E" (in this case, "E5") will have the value "NA").

I tried using an IF function, but the thing is that, the cells from column "E" are also selected from a drop-down list. So, if I change the value after the if function in cell "E", the formula is erased.

What is expected is a code that reads the cells from column "D" and for every cell that has the text "NA", put "NA" in the cell from "E" that is next to it. For example, cell D6 has NA, then the cell E6 has to have this.

Edit: Here's the code that I made. What I want to do now is to make this so it applies to all cells in column.

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)


       Dim celltxt As String

       celltxt = ActiveSheet.Range("D10").Text

       If InStr(1, celltxt, "NA") Then

          ActiveSheet.Range("E10").Value = "NA"

       End If


  End Sub
```

Comment: You need to clarify and provide code you have tried. Also, when you copy a value from a cell and paste into a cell with a formula, you overwrite the formula.

Comment: I added the code I have.

Answer (score 0):

I finished it.

```
Dim rango As Range

Dim i As Long

Set rango = Range("D:D")

For Each cell In rango

    If cell.Value = "NA" Then

        cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "NA"

    End If

Next
```